# Documentation tool for Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am wondering if anyone knows of any tooling, commercial or open source, that provides facilities to document all the DDD artifacts like domain models, contexts, language and other metadata. Metadata are like owners, teams contact, etc2

My search on Google has not revealed much.

Comment: Isn't UML for documenting domain models, at least the structure?

Answer (score 1):

[The contextmapper](https://contextmapper.org/), which can be installed with Visual Code or Eclipse extensions. I use its plantuml generator with [plantuml extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml).

It is an open source project providing a Domain-specific Language and Tools for Strategic Domain-driven Design (DDD), Context Mapping, Bounded Context Modeling, and Service Decomposition.

Comment: Probably to start with, Tool should be able to read the code (C#), to identify Event, Command flows to realize if there is any duplicate. Also to know the flow of these events in an activity - for ex: Create Order flow...etc